# Dart: "Uncaught Error: Error: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node."

Tags: javascript, dart

I an trying to create dynamically this DOM equivalent:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><span>something</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, I have a problem with the following DART code:

```
SpanElement prevPage = new SpanElement();
...
TableElement pageNavigationTable;
pageNavigationTable = new TableElement()..className="pagebar";
Element tbody = pageNavigationTable.createTBody();
TableRowElement row = pageNavigationTable.insertRow(-1);

int cellnum=0;
TableCellElement cell1 = row.insertCell(cellnum++);

cell1.children.add(prevPage);  // At this point exception happens in JS
....
```

I can run it in Dartium Ok, but when running in JS I am getting exception:

"Uncaught Error: Error: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node."

What could be the problem?
Advise, please.

Comment: can you try `cell1.append(prevPage);`

Comment: Sorry, the same result...

Comment: This happens only when I am adding children to a table cell.

Comment: I think you should file a bug at dartbug.com

Comment: Just found this:
http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17332
It is, in fact, a bug.
I will try to resort to:
cell.text = prevPage.outerHTML.

Comment: Great! I remembered reading something along those lines but couldn't find the issue. Polymer 0.10.0-pre.2 already contains a fix.